# Flutter make Clipper Path

Tags: flutter

I want to use the Flutter Custom Clipper to create a shape like the picture below, but it doesn't work. Is there anyone who can help?

[image]

```dart
class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    List<Offset> polygon = [
      Offset(0, 10),
      Offset(size.width - 30, 10),
      Offset(size.width - 25, 0),
      Offset(size.width - 20, 10),
      Offset(size.width, 10),
      Offset(size.width, size.height),
      Offset(0, size.height),
      Offset(0, 10),
    ];

    Path path = Path()
      ..addPolygon(polygon, false)
      ..close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[Svg code]

```
<svg width="132" height="110" viewBox="0 0 132 110" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M111.858 1.73511L111.434 1.05619L111.01 1.73512L107.096 8H5.997C2.96081 8 0.5 10.4627 0.5 13.5V103.5C0.5 106.537 2.96081 109 5.997 109H125.925C128.961 109 131.422 106.537 131.422 103.5V13.5C131.422 10.4627 128.961 8 125.925 8H115.771L111.858 1.73511Z" fill="white" stroke="#EAECEE"/>
</svg>
```

Actually, I used this path through polygon, but I couldn't give it a border, so I guess I don't know much.

Comment: do you have the svg of the image?

Comment: Yes, I have it. I don't know how to upload a file. I edited the svg code in the post

Comment: If you have an svg code. You can use: https://fluttershapemaker.com/#/  open this and click on "SVG to custom paint" on top right corner. this will give you custom paint code. To generate the custom paint, you can paste the svg code and also you can just pick the svg image from your system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```dart
class MyCustomClipper extends CustomPainter {
    @override
    void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
            
Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(111.858,1.73511);
    path_0.lineTo(111.434,1.05619);
    path_0.lineTo(111.01,1.73512);
    path_0.lineTo(107.096,8);
    path_0.lineTo(5.997,8);
    path_0.cubicTo(2.96081,8,0.5,10.4627,0.5,13.5);
    path_0.lineTo(0.5,103.5);
    path_0.cubicTo(0.5,106.537,2.96081,109,5.997,109);
    path_0.lineTo(125.925,109);
    path_0.cubicTo(128.961,109,131.422,106.537,131.422,103.5);
    path_0.lineTo(131.422,13.5);
    path_0.cubicTo(131.422,10.4627,128.961,8,125.925,8);
    path_0.lineTo(115.771,8);
    path_0.lineTo(111.858,1.73511);
    path_0.close();

Paint paint_0_stroke = Paint()..style=PaintingStyle.stroke..strokeWidth=2;
paint_0_stroke.color=Color(0xffEAECEE).withOpacity(1.0);
canvas.drawPath(path_0,paint_0_stroke);

Paint paint_0_fill = Paint()..style=PaintingStyle.fill;
paint_0_fill.color = Colors.white.withOpacity(1.0);
canvas.drawPath(path_0,paint_0_fill);
```

using [Flutter Shape Maker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/#/) you can create CustomPainter code from any svg.

Comment: if you want to create a custom shape then you should follow the way how flutter creates its own shapes, like `CircleBorder`, `RoundedRectangleBorder`, `StadiumBorder` etc, they don't extend `CustomPainter`

Comment: @pskink how they create it?

Comment: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ba39319843/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/circle_border.dart#L31 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ba39319843/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/rounded_rectangle_border.dart#L26

Comment: @pskink can you share the code please how to use that in this example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code belo

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: MyPainter(),
              child: Container(
                  height: 300,
                width:400,
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 20, top: 20),
                  child: Center(
                    child:
                        Text("Some content",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            )),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    Paint stroke = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 6.0
      ..color = Colors.green;
    Path path = Path();

    // Path number 1

    paint.color = Color(0x3d3ded).withOpacity(1);
    path = Path();
    path.moveTo(size.width * 0.14, size.height * 0.11);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.14, size.height * 0.11, size.width * 0.05,
        size.height * 0.11, size.width * 0.05, size.height * 0.11);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.01, size.height * 0.11, 0, size.height * 0.16,
        0, size.height * 0.19);
    path.cubicTo(
        0, size.height * 0.19, 0, size.height * 0.9, 0, size.height * 0.9);
    path.cubicTo(0, size.height, size.width * 0.04, size.height,
        size.width * 0.06, size.height);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.06, size.height, size.width * 0.94, size.height,
        size.width * 0.94, size.height);
    path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height, size.width, size.height * 0.93,
        size.width, size.height * 0.9);
    path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height * 0.9, size.width, size.height * 0.19,
        size.width, size.height * 0.19);
    path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height * 0.11, size.width * 0.96,
        size.height * 0.1, size.width * 0.94, size.height * 0.11);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.94, size.height * 0.11, size.width * 0.27,
        size.height * 0.11, size.width * 0.27, size.height * 0.11);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.27, size.height * 0.11, size.width / 5, 0,
        size.width / 5, 0);
    path.cubicTo(size.width / 5, 0, size.width * 0.14, size.height * 0.11,
        size.width * 0.14, size.height * 0.11);
    path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.14, size.height * 0.11, size.width * 0.14,
        size.height * 0.11, size.width * 0.14, size.height * 0.11);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, stroke);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[image: custom shape]

you may have to create a paint for stroke and paint it twice as shown at the end of this code